# What does "that" refer to in "That is bad because..."?

Tags: pronouns

> Giraffes don't need to drink water because they already get some from
>   the leaves they eat. However, when they do drink water, they can drink
>   several gallons at a time.
>
> **That** is bad because a giraffe has to bend down and get into a vulnerable position when drinking.

Comment: The act of them bending down to drink water for an extended period of time.

Comment: The bending down part comes after, it refers to them drinking water. It is bad for them to drink water because they have to bend down. By the way, it is spelled giraffe, not girrafe.

Comment: That specifically refers to "drinking several gallons at a time". As @TrevorD commented, you need to visit our sister site and ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe *that* refers to the act of a giraffe drinking several gallons of water at a time. It's not that drinking itself makes them vulnerable, it's that drinking for a long period of time makes them vulnerable. The main part of the sentence is *they can drink several gallons at a time,* and it's what's closest to *that*. I think it's natural to infer that *that* normally refers to the main expression closest to it, especially when it makes sense logically.

Comment: For a giraffe to drink any quantity of water it has to bend down into a vulnerable position. So actually yes, the act of drinking itself makes them vulnerable. (Obviously if they drink a large volume of water they will remain vulnerable for a longer period.)

Comment: It takes predators time to recognize the vulnerability. I don't believe they pounce immediately. I think it's the fact that they have the time to stalk and pounce that makes it dangerous